# Shell command to update configuration file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Looking for a way to automate enabling a yum repository in CentOS. The configuration file by default looks like:

```
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
failovermethod=priority

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Notice `enabled=0` in the `[remi]` block. That is what needs to be flipped on. The problem is that I can't just search for `enable=0` since the `remi-test` block also has it, but I don't want to enable the test repo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/\[remi\]/,/^ *\[/ s/enabled=0/enabled=1/' your_repo_file
```

where: `/[remi]/,/^ *[/` tells `sed` to only look for block of text from `[remi]` to next `repo` entry, which starts with `[`.

Comment: perfect for a shell script,or to use with cloudinit,ansible.

Comment: Was able to use it for installations specific for PHP56, PHP7 and mysql.yum repos and mysql specifically use blocks for configuration.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i '0,/enabled=0/s//enabled=1/' /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

Comment: This specifically enables the first disabled repo, which limits its general applicability.

Answer (score 2):

```
yum-config-manager [--enable|--disable] rhel-6-server-rpms
```

That works in RHEL, you should be able to do the same in CentOS. Get a repo name from:

```
yum repolist [all|enabled|disabled]
```

That command will show you what is/isn't enabled, but is configured in a /etc/yum.repos.d/.repo file on your system.

yum-config-manager is part of the yum-utils package on RHEL6 and probably EL distros.

Comment: It works (just checked in CentOS 6.9), this is the best way, and also what the Wizard explains: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 1):

`sed(1)` doesn't edit the file in place, it sends the edits to its output. To edit in-place you need to give the `-i` (or `--in-place`) flag. Also, what you are doing is to edit lines that contain `[remi].*enabled`, which you just won't find. You want to limit the replacement to the section starting `[remi]`, which ends with the next `[`:

```
sed -i -e '/\[remi\]/,/^\[/s/enabled=0/enabled=1/' /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{prev=1;}{if($0~/remi-test/)prev=0;else if($0~/\[remi\]/)prev=1;if(prev &&$0~/enabled/)print "enabled=1";else print}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
failovermethod=priority

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

> awk 'BEGIN{prev=1;}{if($0~/remi-test/)prev=0;else if($0~/\[remi\]/)prev=1;if(prev &&$0~/enabled/)print "enabled=1";else print}' temp
[remi]
name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/mirror
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
failovermethod=priority

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-test]
name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
>
```